# How do you remove light armor blocks in tutorial 8?

Tags: space-engineers

How do you remove accidentally placed blocks in tutorial 8: Your First Ship? I can delete blocks with the grinder on my ship but if I accidentally place larger blocks next to my ship it doesn't let you delete them? Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible to remove wrongly placed blocks that are attached to the buildings in the tutorials. This can be considered a bug.

Source: Was able to replicate it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, is this actually a feature we can implement in our own builds or just glitchy code related to tutorial mode? Also is there a way to re-position blocks or place blocks in hard to reach places? Specifically in reference to this tutorial I am having a problem with placing blocks on top and underneath because of the angles or hitting the floor.

Comment: @CodeCamper Those questions might warrant separate questions. Also, don't forget to upvote and accept a question if your question has been answered.